# How to catch Bad Request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, intellij-idea

I'm creating a simple REST Service where I can do crud operations over users.

For creating users, I wrote the following function:

```
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam String platform, @RequestParam String platformID, @RequestParam String wishlist) {
        if(name != "" && email != "" && password != "" && platform != "" && platformID != "" && wishlist != "") {
            User user = new User(name, email, password, platform, platformID, wishlist);
            User result = userRepository.save(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity("The user can not be added because it is not complete", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
```

As you see, I provide the user info in the request parameters. I want to have it so that if there is a parameter missing in the requested URL, the bottom line of the function is executed. However, when parameters are missing I automatically get back a Bad Request http error. Does anybody know how to catch such an error or change the text in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default `@RequestParam` is required (property `required = true`). You can do something like this `@RequestParam(required = false)`

**UPDATE 1**: I also notice that you use `!=` to compare string. you have to use something like `user != null && !user.eqauls("")`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use **@ControllerAdvice/@RestControllerAdvice**

It allows you to handle exceptions across the whole application and you can customize the response to your client from this handler. Think this as a kind of interceptor.

Please check the following sample code snippet

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> illegalArgumentExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException e) {
           //ErrorResponse is the custom response model
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
     }
    
}
```